# spThin - plotThin function "error in xy.coords

Tags: r, plot

I am using package spThin to thin species occurrence records(which is a dataframe of species, latitude and longitude (for each occurrence). I would like to use `plotThin` to double-check if I am using the ideal amount of repetitions for thinning. I can use the `thin` function just fine.

Here is how my code looks for the `thin` function

```
gandsthin <- 
  thin( loc.data = gandscoor, 
        lat.col = "decimalLatitude", long.col = "decimalLongitude", 
        spec.col = "acceptedScientificName", 
        thin.par = 10, reps = 1, 
        locs.thinned.list.return = TRUE, 
        write.files = FALSE, 
        write.log.file = FALSE)
```

which shows in the console this...

```
********************************************** 
 Beginning Spatial Thinning.
 Script Started at: Sat Jun 10 15:07:46 2023
lat.long.thin.count
126 
  1 
[1] "Maximum number of records after thinning: 126"
[1] "Number of data.frames with max records: 1"
[1] "No files written for this run."
```

It also produces a `gandsthin` dataframe which looks like this...
[image: gandsthin]

Now when I use the plotThin function on `gandsthin` I get this error message

```
> plotThin(gandsthin)
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

Interestingly, the plotThin function worked before for me with this exact data and code so not sure why its not now, I restarted R thinking it might have worked again but it didn't. I am not sure where to check if x and y lengths differ. I am not sure why they would differ, because every latitude has a longitude and a species name but I totally might be missing something.